# Why fs.readFile takes too much time on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just downloaded `node v4.4.3 LTS` and was running this simple code.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./tmp/Test.txt', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Test.txt contains

```
"hello world"
```

It takes around 20 seconds to give the log.

What could be possible reasons?

`node.exe` is in `D:/node.js` and pathvariable is assigned.

Comment: Just in case I confirm there's no such problem on node 6 64 bits / Ubuntu.

Comment: Does it happen when you use `fs.readFileSync`? Does it happen when reading other files too?

Comment: It happens for each file. Let me check 'synch'

Comment: How long does it take to run an empty `test.js` file?

Comment: What is the version of Windows OS?

Comment: Sync would be `console.log(fs.readFileSync('./tmp/Test.txt', 'utf8'))`

Comment: Also if this is the whole file and you run it like `node file.js` then try logging above the `fs.readFile` to see whether it is really the file operation that takes so long or just the script startup.

Comment: I guess problem is with systemenvironment varialbe. I removed the path varialbe to node js and tried directly on node.exe the same thing. It was ok .

Comment: Would you mind answering your own question then with the details of what went wrong and what solved it, for others that will encounter the same problem later?

Comment: of course Let me do detailed analysis first. Let me try LTS version too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is just an observation and not the answer.**

This is my `D:/node.js`

```
Name                        Size            Date Modified
node_modules/                           4/16/16, 1:51:11 PM
node_etw_provider.man       6.5 kB      2/16/16, 10:48:12 PM
node_perfctr_provider.man   4.9 kB      3/8/16, 10:48:08 PM
node.exe                    13.6 MB     5/2/16, 11:35:12 AM
nodevars.bat                702 B       3/8/16, 10:48:10 PM
npm                         623 B       3/3/16, 11:01:58 PM
npm.bat                     570 B       4/16/16, 2:03:03 PM
```

node.exe is  v4.4.3LTS

When I tried this simple code using it, it is taking around 20 seconds to run.

Please note that, the other data files are manually downloaded from https://github.com/npm/npm

So this might be the problem. I tried V6.0 without any problem. I also tried v4.4.3LTS node.exe without path variable assigned and it worked perfect. So I guess, is because v4.4.3LTS is trying some process (manual npm) before running.